# Any php framework that supports SQL server 2008?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, frameworks

Anybody know any php frameworks that supports full SQL server 2008 ??

Answer (score 1):

I know Codeigniter supports mssql.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for a framework specific connection to MS SQL server however PHP does have support for SQL server connections with mssql_connect();

[mssql_connect()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

Comment: Didn't they changed to sqlsrv_connect()

Comment: Not that I know of, doesnt seem to be a function called sqlsrv_connect in the core php library: http://us3.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sqlsrv_connect%28%29

looking deeper that function seems to be a product of a msdn php driver support:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Well I tried mssql_connect() I can't seem to connect to the SQL server  I modified php.ini uncomment it the mssql extn too any idea Im just so confused

Comment: hey so here is the answer (its been awhile since I have uses mssql_connect) basically this extension has been dropped in php 5.3 for windows and the SqlSvr is the alternative. So @ user644051 was on the right path, check out these requirements then click the link to MSDN:

http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php

Answer (score 0):

As user644051 had already mentioned below - present driver to connect CI with MSSQL is SqlSrv.

I managed to connect CI with MS SQL 2008 and started to work with it.

BUT the way you have to twist your CI code to force database to cough up the results... is not worth the effort.

Bottom line: MSSQL driver is not optimized to work flowlessly with CI contrary to MYSQL which allows for easy and smooth work.

For example SqlSrv driver doesn't work for CI insert_batch().

Although I'd like to use flexibility that MSSQL server offers - at the moment we have to wait for a driver that will allow for such a luxury in CI.
So for the moment I discourage you to use CI with MSSQL.